# Extract nested JSON element using scala

Tags: json, scala, nested, json4s

I have the following code in Scala. My goal is to extract the value(s) of a key without knowing how many and how deep they are.

---

```
    import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
    import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, JField, JObject, JString, JValue}

    object jsonLift {

        implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

        val js = parse(
            """
    {
      "url": "imap.yahoo.com",
        "credentials": {
        "username": "myusername",
        "password": "mypassword"
         },
        "some key":{
            "other key": {
                "username": "hello"
            }
        }
    }
            """)


            def getElem(elem: String, json:JValue) = for {
                    JObject(child) <- json
                    JField(elem, JString(value)) <- child       // this does not return the expected result
    //              JField("username", JString(value)) <- child // this returns the expected result
                } yield  value


        def main(args: Array[String]) {

            val result = getElem("username", js)
            println(result)

        }
    }
```

The result of the above code is `List(imap.yahoo.com, myusername, mypassword, hello)` which is not what I am expecting. My expected result is `List(myusername, hello)`.

However, if I change the variable `elem`, directly inside the method `getElem`, with the key (as string) that I am interested in (Eg: "username") I get the expected result: `List(myusername, hello)` which are all the values of the key "username".

How can I get the expected list of value(s) by calling the method `getElem` with the name of the JSON key as argument? Eg: `getElem("JSON key", json)`

Thank you!

Comment: The expected result should be `List(myusername, hello)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `getElem` to

```
def getElem(elem: String, json:JValue) = for {
  JObject(child) <- json
  JField(`elem`, JString(value)) <- child
} yield  value
```

Without the backticks around `elem` on the RHS, you are binding the first element of `type JField = (String, JValue)` to a new name `elem` and shadowing the method parameter `elem`

Comment: I did not know that using backticks would work like that and match in this way. Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: I did not know that either. Looks like a scala-esque solution. Thank you !!! Indeed it returns the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue here is that when you use:

```
JField(elem, JString(value)) <- child
```

inside your for comprehension, this new definition of `elem` shadows the `elem` which you passed into the `getElem` method.

I guess your intent was that this would match if the value `elem` passed into `getElem` was the same as the name of the `JField`. This is not how it works however, and instead, the symbol elem is bound to the key name.

You can achieve what you want with a small alteration to the line above as follows:

```
JField(key, JString(value)) <- child if key == elem
```

which will bind the value to `value` only if the name of the `JField` matches `elem`.